# MySQL - Delete event w/datediff condition is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, events

I know there is plenty of answers related to my issue, but I could not get to the solution yet.

I created an event that must delete rows on a table (table_name) when 730 days pass since an specific date (spec_date).

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `delete_old_clients`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2022-10-13 00:00:00'
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN
   delete from table_name
   where datediff(now(), spec_date)>730;    
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

GLOBAL event_scheduler is ON and processlist is working well:

```
5   event_scheduler localhost       Daemon  53  Waiting for next activation
```

But for some reason rows are not being deleted. Am i missing sth?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks fine to me. How big is the table, maybe it's just taking a long time? Try using `WHERE spec_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 730 DAY)`. If there's an index on `spec_date`, this will use it.

Comment: No, only 100 rows, but the event it is not deleting anything. Could be something related with  autocommit?

Comment: Auto commit is only relevant if you're executing multiple queries and want to control whether to commit after each one or group them into a transaction. Since you only have one query, it's irrelevant.

Comment: Are you sure the query is running? If you add something else, like an `INSERT`, do you see that?

Comment: What does `select count(*) from table_name where datediff(now(), spec_date)>730` return?

Comment: @Barmar it shows 14 rows from a total of 95 rows. Those 14 rows are the ones which the event must delete, but it is not working properly.

Comment: I can't see any reason why it's not working. Are other scheduled events working?